# How can i test the rest endpoints which gives response in AVRO format using karate?

Tags: karate

Karate has been super helpful to validate our rest apis which gives json response. Now we have apis which gives us response in avro format. May also need to send the payload in avro format. How can i test the rest endpoints which gives response in AVRO format using karate? Is there any easy way I can tweak and get it done. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my suggestion, and in my opinion this will work very well.

Write a simple Java utility, maybe a static method that can take JSON and convert it to AVRO and vice versa.

Now you can define all your request data as JSON - but just before you make the request to the server, convert it to AVRO. I am not sure if the server call is HTTP or not. If it is HTTP - then you know what to do in Karate, just send binary as the request body etc.

Else you may not even use the Karate HTTP DSL like `method`, `request` etc. You have to write one more Java helper that will take your JSON (or AVRO) and make the call to the server (specific for your project) and return the response, converted back to JSON.  For example:

```
* def Utils = Java.type('com.myco.avro.Utils')
* def json = { hello: 'world' }
* def req = Utils.toAvro(json)
* def res = Utils.send(req)
# you can combine this with the above
* def response = Utils.fromAvro(res)
* match response == { success: true }
```

Yes, you might be using Karate mostly for matching, reporting, environments etc. Which is still valuable ! Many people don't realize that HTTP is just 10% of what Karate can do for you.

Comment: Tanks @peter thomas. it is http call. i will try this solution.